# Redux Thunk in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, redux, redux-thunk

I'm trying to get a better understanding of ThunkDispatch function and TypeScript. Got this code for using redux and thunk.

```
// This is redux-thunk source code
import { Middleware, Action, AnyAction } from "redux";

export interface ThunkDispatch<S, E, A extends Action> {
  <T extends A>(action: T): T;
  <R>(asyncAction: ThunkAction<R, S, E, A>): R;
}

export type ThunkAction<R, S, E, A extends Action> = (
  dispatch: ThunkDispatch<S, E, A>,
  getState: () => S,
  extraArgument: E
) => R;

===================

import { Action } from 'redux'
import { ThunkAction } from 'redux-thunk'
import { ThunkDispatch } from 'redux-thunk'

interface ReduxState {
  // redux states
}

type ThunkResult<R> = ThunkAction<R, ReduxState, undefined, Action>
type ReduxDispatch = ThunkDispatch<ReduxState, undefined, Action>

const loadAppData = (): ThunkResult<void> => async (dispatch, getState) => {
  // get app data
  dispatch(MyAction.getAppDataSuccess(17))
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch: ReduxDispatch) => ({
  loadAppData: () => dispatch(loadAppData()),
})
```

My current understanding:

```
export interface ThunkDispatch<S, E, A extends Action> {
  <T extends A>(action: T): T;
  <R>(asyncAction: ThunkAction<R, S, E, A>): R;
}
```

The `ThunkDispatch` is an interface with 2 properties, let's call them A and B. A is a function with a parameter called `action` type of `T` and returns something that is a type of `T`. Similarly, for B, it's a function with a parameter called `asyncAction` type of `ThunkAction<R, S, E, A>` and returns something that is a type of `R`.

**Question** 
Does are the `<T extends A>` and `<R>` part just to imply a new generic type?

My current understanding:

```
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch: ReduxDispatch) => ({
  loadAppData: () => dispatch(loadAppData()),
})
```

`dispatch` as a parameter is a type of `ReduxDispatch` which is an interface with 2 property functions.

`loadAppData` is a function that will return a type of `ThunkResult<void>`, which is equivalent to `ThunkAction<Void, ReduxState, undefined, Action>`. If we put those types into the `ThunkAction` definition, it matches to the signature of `async (dispatch, getState) => { ... }`

**Question**
The `dispatch(loadAppData())` in the `mapDispatchToProps`, `loadAppData()` returns a `ThunkResult<void>` which is essentially a function. `dispatch` is just an interface with 2 property functions, then this syntax doesn't make sense to me, `interface(func)`

If I misunderstood anything, please point it out! Thanks

Comment: "The ThunkDispatch is an interface with 2 properties" --- that's why you're confused. `ThunkDispatch` is a function with 2 overloads. One accepts `action: T`, another accepts `asyncAction: ThunkAction<R, S, E, A>`.

Comment: Thank you @zerkms Could you give a link to explain this syntax? When I google Typescript function overloading, none of them mentioned this syntax

Comment: And quite interesting, why `ThunkDispatch ` is a function, not an interface?

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#function-types And overloads indirectly come from https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#overloads

Comment: `ThunkDispatch` - it's an interface that describes a function

Comment: Thanks @zerkms that clears all my confusion! If you don't mind to draft an answer, I will mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I personally cannot find a place in the TS handbook that explains the interfaces function overload thoroughly.

All that is available is:

1. [Interfaces :: Function types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#function-types)
2. [Function overloads](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#overloads)

If I'm not wrong the declaration you provided

```
export interface ThunkDispatch<S, E, A extends Action> {
  <T extends A>(action: T): T;
  <R>(asyncAction: ThunkAction<R, S, E, A>): R;
}
```

could be otherwise implemented as a following union of 2 function types:

```
type ThunkDispatch<S, E, A extends Action> = (<T extends A>(action: T) => T) | (<R>(asyncAction: ThunkAction<R, S, E, A>) => R);
```

or

```
type ThunkDispatch<S, E, A extends Action> =
    | (<T extends A>(action: T) => T)
    | (<R>(asyncAction: ThunkAction<R, S, E, A>) => R);
```

Answer (score 0):

Although this is a late reply, it is worthy including it as an answer to this question. From the [Redux Usage with Typescript](https://redux.js.org/recipes/usage-with-typescript/#usage-with-typescript):

Redux Thunk is a commonly used middleware for writing sync and async logic that interacts with the Redux store. Feel free to check out its documentation here. A thunk is a function that returns another function that takes parameters dispatch and getState. Redux Thunk has a built in type ThunkAction which we can use to define types for those arguments:

```
import { Action } from 'redux'
import { sendMessage } from './store/chat/actions'
import { RootState } from './store'
import { ThunkAction } from 'redux-thunk'

export const thunkSendMessage = (
  message: string
): ThunkAction<void, RootState, unknown, Action<string>> => async dispatch => {
  const asyncResp = await exampleAPI()
  dispatch(
    sendMessage({
      message,
      user: asyncResp,
      timestamp: new Date().getTime()
    })
  )
}
```